# Creating and Verifying PKCS #7 signatures in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pkcs#7

Im trying to figure out how to generate and verify PKCS #7 signatures in VB.net. These signatures need to be stored in a separate file to the data they are verifying (eg test.dat and test.dat.sig).  Ive found code to generate signatures in another question, but cant figure out how to verify them

```
Public Sub SignFile(ByVal theFilename As String, ByVal theCertFile As String, ByVal thePassword As String, ByVal theDestination As String)
    Dim aCertificate = New X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(theCertFile, thePassword)
    Dim aByteArray = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(theFilename)
    Dim anOid = New System.Security.Cryptography.Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.2")
    Dim aContentInfo = New Pkcs.ContentInfo(anOid, aByteArray)
    Dim aSignedCms = New Pkcs.SignedCms(aContentInfo, True)
    Dim aCmsSigner = New Pkcs.CmsSigner(Pkcs.SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, aCertificate)

    aSignedCms.ComputeSignature(aCmsSigner)
    Dim aSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(aSignedCms.Encode())
    IO.File.WriteAllText(theDestination, aSignature)
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following might help you for Verifying CMS/PKCS#7 Signatures

> http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/verify/index.html